# IOS cannot set VPN programmatically

Tags: ios, vpn

Kindly asking for help - I've tried to implements things, described in [this great post](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/); also I've read tons of different info on internet - but I still can't create VPN and make it work.
I've tried also to download ready .mobileconfig files - they are installed ok, but I'm not able to manage them from my app.
If possible - can you share working code? Certainly, without your credentials - I'll replace them with my one's.

What do I need - simple app, that allows to install/edit and enable/disable VPN connection (at this moment at least pptp and l2tp).
Great thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you managed it? I also have a .mobileconfig file and a .p12 certificate. I guess I should somehow 'parse' the .mobileconfig file since it has a lot information in it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I switched to Android development soon after this question and I even don't remember, how it ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As far as I know, in iOS you can only set programmatically VPN connection with only IPSec and IKEv2 protocols
2. For me it was very helpful to find this great example of such application https://github.com/lexrus/VPNOn where you can find the examples of both available types of connections to VPN. I think critical point in creating of VPN connection is to provide valid keychain references to your credentials:

`p.passwordReference = [VPN user password from keychain];`

`p.sharedSecretReference = [VPN server shared secret from keychain];`